# fgets() doesn't read the full line

Tags: php, fgets

I have a file which has the following long single line random string:

```
fuzzero^G5%eLz@5?0jzlqCA};iBdi>hSa0Uc"DS{m*JVMPMN),)dBnbwGNKYE#uP$3@WGyV#kjC&(2yW1l`DJ,`3Mz#5gbU}eAUU)uB7N><A"qa;M{y9{mdKW"P?4o`jZI<M?tTElL<f?3aC1JM0&ZKGTewYDk;g$`#UhAcD05S>8#tap'aaUVQr`14rl0I3`oY6Z`JZ'fR3:{em"owN{0"(1}en}Wr*,3>Z<AC(Q8?M64(0siNrjGdkEsIB2)n2?e@%PiRjqH&xLSx<|,j8Fxt{Z|z@YW%P|JyE@3Y6KID9f`25)ldtSGrvw@b9C'YrDa&jeIpY5#(lR`qFaE)#,ecv'oFwihYWsI"G5ija,5wQ'Wa4f}*ec{K6n3DGlfgNXa8#tr>sxo}s,7xe4jsgh?nF"!,e"g#Qq|xTgp0ON{;M5s!aL6r$}On>sm5lD(?$XoB<NBGezC!F%EQuL;cIJzz?WFcds2;3rx;<)C6m<*#Xqw6|riy|S(@ts<HU'CYl)Teordizuzfeid
```

I wrote php code to read this line:

```
$myfile = fopen($path, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt=fgets($myfile);
echo $txt;

fclose($myfile);
```

the output is part of the random string:

```
fuzzero^G5%eLz@5?0jzlqCA};iBdi>hSa0Uc"DS{m*JVMPMN),)dBnbwGNKYE#uP$3@WGyV#kjC&(2yW1l`DJ,`3Mz#5gbU}eAUU)uB7N>8#tap'aaUVQr`14rl0I3`oY6Z`JZ'fR3:{em"owN{0"(1}en}Wr*,3>Zsxo}s,7xe4jsgh?nF"!,e"g#Qq|xTgp0ON{;M5s!aL6r$}On>sm5lD(?$XoB
```

How can I read and show the complete string?

Comment: And fgets() is required?

Comment: It seems one part is "ripped out", `<A"qa;M{y9{mdKW"P?4o`jZI<M?tTElL<f?3aC1JM0&ZKGTewYDk;g$`#UhAcD05S>` to be precise.

Comment: Maybe PHP is not detecting the line ending correctly in your file. Did you try to set `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` ?

Comment: Is it possible PHP tries to interpret the ripped-out part as a (whatever-) tag?

Comment: @TobiasF. PHP doesn't interpret HTML (except when it is specifically told to do it ([`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php), [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code works fine. It reads 527 bytes from the file.

If you run this PHP script in the browser, the part that you think it misses (`<A"qa;M{y9{mdKW"P?4ojZI<M?tTElL<f?3aC1JM0&ZKGTewYDk;g$#UhAcD‌​05S>`) looks like an HTML element and it is not displayed by the browser.

Check the Page Source (find in in the menu or in the Developer Tools) to see the exact output produced by the script.

Or, even better, use the PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to tell the browser the content generated by the script is text, not HTML:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$myfile = fopen($path, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt=fgets($myfile);
echo $txt;

fclose($myfile);
```

If you want to read the entire content of the file in a single shot then PHP provides the function [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) specifically for this purpose:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$txt = file_get_contents($path);
echo($txt);
```

Comment: `header('text/plain');` doesn't work it has no impact I am using Chrome

Comment: It should be `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. I corrected the answer now. Thank you for finding it.